# How to get Calander data from an online timetabling website

Tags: web-scraping, google-calendar-api, timetable

My school uses TeachWorks to timetable our lessons. I am leaving school soon and thus will lose access to my account.  While I still have a login, I would like to download all my school timetables from the last five years.  Can anyone give advice on how I can achieve this?

The calendar isn't an embedded google calendar or anything similar and has no obvious way of downloading the data.

NB: the school I go to is very small and I've asked our IT chap but he doesn't know (or can't be bothered) to provide me with this info.  He gave me permission to get it myself should I want as it is my data.

Comment: Have you reached out to [TeachWorks Support](https://teachworks.com/faq) for this already? Web-scraping will be impossible if the data is being updated by a script _(e.g. not a static HTML data)_.